# SQL Server Amount Split

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below 2 tables in SQL Server database.

Customer Main Expense Table

```
ReportID CustomerID  TotalExpenseAmount
1000       1          200
1001       2          600
```

Attendee Table

```
ReportID AttendeeName
1000        Mark
1000        Sam
1000        Joe
```

There is no amount at attendee level. I have need to manually calculate individual attendee amount as mentioned below. (i.e split TotalExpenseAmount based on number of attendees and ensure individual split figures round to 2 decimals and sums up to the TotalExpenseAmount exactly)

The final report should look like:

```
ReportID CustID AttendeeName TotalAmount AttendeeAmount
1000       1      Mark          200         66.66
1000       1      Sam           200         66.66
1000       1      Joe           200         66.68
```

The final report will have about 1,50,000 records. If you notice the attendee amount I have rounded the last one in such a way that the totals match to 200. What is the best way to write an efficient SQL query in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something similar to @Gordon's answer but using a CTE instead.

```
with CTECount AS (
                  select a.ReportId, a.AttendeeName, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ReportId ORDER BY A.AttendeeName) [RowNum],
                        COUNT(A.AttendeeName) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ReportId) [AttendeeCount],
                        CAST(c.TotalExpenseAmount / (COUNT(A.AttendeeName) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ReportId)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) [PerAmount]
                  FROM @Customer C INNER JOIN @Attendee A ON A.ReportId = C.ReportID 

                  )
SELECT CT.ReportID, CT.CustomerId, AT.AttendeeName, 
       CASE WHEN CC.RowNum = 1 THEN  CT.TotalExpenseAmount - CC.PerAmount *              (CC.AttendeeCount - 1)
            ELSE CC.PerAmount END [AttendeeAmount]
FROM @Customer CT INNER JOIN @Attendee AT 
        ON CT.ReportID = AT.ReportId 
    INNER JOIN CTECount CC 
        ON CC.ReportId = CT.ReportID AND CC.AttendeeName = AT.AttendeeName
```

I like the CTE because it allows me to separate the different aspects of the query.  The cool thing that @Gordon used was the Case statement and the inner calculation to have the lines total correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select ReportID, CustID, AttendeeName, TotalAmount,
       (case when seqnum = 1
             then TotalAmount - perAttendee * (cnt - 1)
             else perAttendee
        end) as AttendeeAmount
from (select a.ReportID, a.CustID, a.AttendeeName, e.TotalAmount,
             row_number() over (partition by reportId order by AttendeeName) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by reportId) as cnt,
             cast(TotalAmount * 1.0 / count(*) over (partition by reportId) as decimal(10, 2)) as perAttendee
      from attendee a join
           expense e
           on a.ReportID = e.ReportID
     ) ae;
```

The `perAttendee` amount is calculated in the subquery.  This is rounded down by using `cast()` (only because `floor()` doesn't accept a decimal places argument).  For one of the rows, the amount is the total minus the sum of all the other attendees.